# Can JavaScript in Chrome for iOS play sounds?

Tags: javascript, chrome-for-ios

Apple have long blocked mobile Safari from playing sounds – the usual JavaScript commands to play sounds just don't work on it. Does the Chrime browser for iOS, released today, allow sounds to be played?

Ps. Sounds induced by the user can be played on both – my question referred to sounds kicked off by JavaScript only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chrome for iOS](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/mobile/ios.html) is [just a skin over the built in Safari browser](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2406477,00.asp).  That is, it is *not* the Chrome version of WebKit.  It should behave identically to Safari itself.  If Safari is blocked from playing sounds, so will the Chrome browser.